# How can I change column names without messing all my queries?

Tags: json, excel, powerbi

I want to change column name from Value to Stoc. How can I do this without messing connections?

I'm New with Power query and json files and I don't know if I can change it from Excel or if I must rewrite json file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the the little gear next to the Source step to edit the data.
[image]

Without knowing more about your model and what calculations are dependant on this, you could try adding a new column and using that for your slicer. Something like:
[image]

Comment: If I do this my Slicer Will have 'blank' instead of renamed value

Comment: You will also need to update any other table / calculation that is dependent on that value. Or try this, leave it as it is and add a second column to that table with the new values.
Maybe call the column "Slicer" and add "Stoc", "Volume". Then update the slicer to use this new column. I've updated my answer with more info on this.